# Retrieving ViewModel with multiple list objects once its posted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a viewmodel class like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string VendorService { get; set; }
    public List<ResponseView> responseList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller has get and post edit actions:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    List<ResponseView> resp = getResponseView(id); //get the list of ResponseView objects.
    ViewModel view = new ViewModel();
    view.responseList = resp;
    view.VendorService = "Car Manufacturer";
    return View(view);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel view)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        List<ResponseView> respList = new List<ResponseView>();
        respList = view.responseList;

        foreach(ResponseView resp in respList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(resp.Question);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("editConfirm");
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

Edit.cshtml

```
@model Tools.Models.ViewModel
@{
  List<Tools.Models.ResponseView> respList= Model.responseList as List<Tools.Models.ResponseView;
}

        @foreach (var item in respList)
        {
           <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Response, "" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Response, "", "" })
           </div>
         }
```

I am able to display the view and all the data in the View Model as required. But I am getting a null pointer reference when I try to retrieve the response in my post action, on foreach line below.

```
    List<ResponseView> respList = new List<ResponseView>();
    respList = view.responseList;

    foreach(ResponseView resp in respList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(resp.Response);
    }
```

Comment: try with [FromBody] in public ActionResult Edit([FromBody] ViewModel view) and typecast respList = view.responseList as List<ResponseView>;

Comment: I am getting a Type or namespace error when using [FromBody]. I am using System.Web and System.Net in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `for` instead `foreach` . Please try this,

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.responseList.Count; ++i) {
<div>
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.responseList[i].Response, "")
</div>
```